# how should I send messages from server to client in WinSock's UDP?

Tags: sockets, udp, winsock

I am learning WinSock UDP. Most tutorials I've seen ask me to:

On server side:

```
SOCKET socked = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)
bind(...);
for(;;) { recvfrom(..); }
```

On client side:

```
SOCKET socked = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
sendto(...);
```

But I wonder how can I do other way, send data from server to client. I don't know client's port (I figured out it vary every sendto call), and I want to be able to connect client behihd NAT to server and still recive data from server.

How it is done in modern games?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two questions in there.

#### Finding the address

The function `recvfrom` is declared:

```
int recvfrom(
  __in         SOCKET s,
  __out        char *buf,
  __in         int len,
  __in         int flags,
  __out        struct sockaddr *from, /* <--- */
  __inout_opt  int *fromlen           /* <--- */
);
```

So you can use `from` and `fromlen` in `sendto`.

```
sendto(..., (SOCKADDR *)from, *fromlen);
```

#### NAT

The NAT-box should automatically allow the server to "*answer*" to the datagram sent by the client. So, the mere fact that the client sent a datagram causes the NAT-box to ephemerally (a few minutes?) open a port to allow traffic return.

Comment: I tested on localhost and found out that each time the recvfrom is called it recives diffrent port. How should I handle this?

Comment: Use it in `sendto`. Read my answer again.